# creating a responsive nav with hamburger instead of text as dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have implemented the JavaScript plug-in [from](http://responsive-nav.com/) but can't seem to figure out how to make the dropdown button a hamburger....has anyone successfully done this?

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="scripts/responsive-nav.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <!-- <div id="main-content">-->
        <div id="main-col">

            <nav class="nav-collapse">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="menu-1.html">MENU</a></li>             
                    <li><a href="catering.html">CATERING</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>  
<script>
    var nav = responsiveNav(".nav-collapse", { // Selector
        animate: true, // Boolean: Use CSS3 transitions, true or false
        transition: 284, // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
        label: "MENU", // String: Label for the navigation toggle
        insert: "after", // String: Insert the toggle before or after the navigation
        customToggle: "", // Selector: Specify the ID of a custom toggle
        closeOnNavClick: false, // Boolean: Close the navigation when one of the            links are clicked
        openPos: "relative", // String: Position of the opened nav, relative or static
        navClass: "nav-collapse", // String: Default CSS class. If changed, you need            to edit the CSS too!
        navActiveClass: "js-nav-active", // String: Class that is added to  element             when nav is active
        jsClass: "js", // String: 'JS enabled' class which is added to  element
        init: function(){}, // Function: Init callback
        open: function(){}, // Function: Open callback
        close: function(){} // Function: Close callback
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

and the accompanying css..

```
/*! responsive-nav.js 1.0.36 by @viljamis */

.nav-collapse ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
list-style: none;
}

.nav-collapse li {
width: 100%;
display: block;
}

.js .nav-collapse {
clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
max-height: 0;
position: absolute;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
 zoom: 1;
}

.nav-collapse.opened {
max-height: 9999px;
}

.nav-toggle {
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
margin-left: 83%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
.js .nav-collapse {
position: relative;
}
.js .nav-collapse.closed {
max-height: none;
}
.nav-toggle {
display: none;
}
}
```

Comment: Well... you need hamburger image as background, check their demos... :) http://responsive-nav.com/demo/hamburger.gif Give ID to customToggle and make css for it, using hamburger image.

Comment: i played around with custom toggle, used the code supplied under demos, but in the end i just edited the following rules for .nav-toggle as follows (and added the hamburger.gif as mentioned above  '.nav-toggle {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 45px;
  float: right;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  background: #868686 url("../img/hamburger.gif") no-repeat 50% 50%;
}'